# S.find() из библиотеки string

Tags: строки, c++

Какой алгоритм использует s.find() из библиотеки string (C++) для поиска подстроки в строке (КМП или что-то другое)?

Comment: С точки зрения операции `string::find`, КМП использовать не стоит, т. к. он требует длительного препроцессинга строки, который нужен лишь если поиск не будет повторяться (и требует где-то хранить полученную при препроцессинге таблицу, и думать о том, когда её уничтожать). Поэтому скорее всего `string::find` использует наивный алгоритм.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стандарт не накладывает никаких ограничений на сложность std::string::find, поэтому надо смотреть на конкретные имплементации стандартной библиотеки. В реализации библиотеки для gcc, например, используется наивный алгоритм со сложностью O(длина-строки * длина-образца) (см. [`basic_string<...>::find`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/a00999_source.html#l00734), [`char_traits<char>::compare`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/a01033_source.html#l00257)).

Comment: @dzhioev: Мне всё же кажется, там сложность `O(min(длина-строки, длина-образца))` (а `char_traits<char>::compare)` расходует `O(1)`).

Comment: @VladD, не, кажется все-таки O(lstr * lpat).

Смотрите, для строки `aaaaaaaa ...очень много a... aaaaaaab` и образца `aaaac` мы для каждого  `a` (до lstr - lpat) в строке будем вызывать `memcmp()` с длиной образца - 1, которая успешно пробежит до `c` в образце.

Comment: @avp: Ваша правда, туплю.